# How do I insert string into function?

Tags: c++

I have a string which can be inputted by the user:

```
char varname[];
```

I want to put this variable inputted by the user into the `Draw()` function below. However, I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

The original command which works is:

```
t->Draw("somevar>>h", "", "goff");
```

Here, `somevar` is a specific variable. I want to input the variable the user inputted into `varname` in place of this `somevar`. I tried something like the following but it doesn't work:

```
t->Draw(varname">>h", "", "goff");
```

Comment: When asking code-related questions, you should always add a tag for the language you're using. Please [edit] your question to include that tag.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::string`. `char varname[]` is nonsense code in that context. You *cannot* use that without additional work, and that notation is effectively wrong.

Comment: C++ variables only exist when compiling. After that they are *permanently gone*. As such you cannot do this. You probably need a `std::map` look-up table if you're referring to things by name. How does `t->Draw()` know about "somevar" at all? Where is that `Draw()` function even from?

Comment: Wait, is this just about concatenating strings? If so, `std::string` can be added, as in `s1 + s2` and then `c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about concatenating the literal contents of a variable with a predictable name, then:

```cpp
std::string arg = getName();

arg.append("<<h");

t->Draw(arg.c_str(), "", "goff");
```